# Extract folder names and create directory

Tags: bash

I have to extract folder names (folder10 folder44 etc) using for loop and make directory using each folder names but I get file names (file1 file12) and I get an error while creating directory i.e "Directory cannot be created". I have to operate on .txt files in my pipeline so I can't skip /home/data/folder*/file* in for loop

How can I get folder names instead of file names

```
 #!/bin/bash
 $out_dir=/home/data/results
 for file in /home/data/folder*/file*
 do
     txtFile=${file##*/}
     id=${txtFile%.txt}

     echo "mkdir -p $out_dir/"${id}""

 done
```

Folders and File structure

```
 /home/data/folder10/file1/file1.txt
 /home/data/folder44/file12/file12.txt
 /home/data/folder100/file3/file3.txt
 /home/data/folder250/file4/file4.txt
 /home/data/folder1245/file5/file5.txt
```

output which I get
    mkdir -p /home/data/results/file1
    mkdir -p /home/data/results/file12
    mkdir -p /home/data/results/file3

expected output will be

```
mkdir -p /home/data/results/folder10
mkdir -p /home/data/results/folder44
mkdir -p /home/data/results/folder100
```

Comment: You are stripping off the path of the file in that first line and then stripping off the suffix in the second. If you want the path that isn't going to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this:

```
#!/bin/bash
out_dir=/home/data/results
for file in /home/data/folder*/file*.txt; do
    folder=${file%/*}
    mkdir -p "$out_dir/${folder##*/}"
done
```

Or this:

```
#!/bin/bash
out_dir=/home/data/results
for file in /home/data/folder*/file*/file*.txt; do
    folder=${file%/*/*}
    mkdir -p "$out_dir/${folder##*/}"
done
```

Comment: thanks but in $id I will get file names not the folder names. I have specified it above